# Driver get within loop repeats opening chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

How to reduce number of selenium running google chrome while getting data. Precisely, I have this code in for which iterate more than 200 times:

```
try:
    DRIVER_PATH = '/home/Selenium-drivers/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
    driver.get(url_specific_wine)
    regions = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="MainContent"]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[5]/div[4]/div/div/div[9]/div[2]').text

except:
    regions = ''
    all_regions.append(regions)
```

That will open a google chrome with each time. How to avoid that?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are actually using BeautifulSoup, but instead using the lxml module manually instead of giving it to BS.

Comment: @DanP I used beautiful soup to get to the url for specific sfuff on page (url_specific_wine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This your current code can be improved at least in 2 points:
1.

```py
DRIVER_PATH = '/home/Selenium-drivers/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
```

Should be taken out of the loop.
2.
You should use Expected Conditions explicit waits, something like this:

```py
DRIVER_PATH = '/home/Selenium-drivers/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
try:
    driver.get(url_specific_wine)
    regions = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="MainContent"]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[5]/div[4]/div/div/div[9]/div[2]'))).text
except:
    regions = ''
    all_regions.append(regions)
```

3. 

`//*[@id="MainContent"]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[5]/div[4]/div/div/div[9]/div[2]` XPath locator seems to be not reliable. I have no idea what element are you trying to locate, by the locator have to be improved here.
In order to use `wait` object above you will need the following imports

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```